# Why does my horizontal navigation bar take the space of the content area?

Tags: html, css

I have a questions about a horizontal navigation bar. I want to create a page with an image as header (height:100px), a horizontal navigation bar and finally the content area ( height:768px). I wonder why the navigation bar taks place in the content area (that means that the content area gets smaller than 768px). How can I avoid this behaviour? Instead, I'd like to shift the content area downwards about the size of the navigation bar.

This is my css code:

```
* {
         margin:0;
         padding:0;
}

body {
         background:#FFFFFF;
}

#frame {
         margin: auto;
         width: 1024px;
         height: 768px;
}

#header {
         width:100%;
         height:100px;
         background-image:url(image.jpg);
}

#navigation {
         width: 100%;
         float: left;
         list-style: none;
         background: #f2f2f2;
}

#navigation li {
         list-style: none;
         display: inline;
         float: left;
}

#navigation a {
         display: block;
         padding: 8px 15px;
         text-decoration: none;
         font-weight: bold;
         color: #069;
         border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#navigation a:hover {
         color: #c00;
         background-color: #fff;
}

#content {
    background: #EBF7FF;
    width: 1024px;
    height:768px;       
    text-align: justify;
}
```

and this is the html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>
<body text="#000000" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" link="#FF0000" alink="#FF0000" vlink="#FF0000">

<div id="frame">

<div id="header">

</div>

 <ul id="navigation">
          <li><a href="main.html" target="_self">text1</a></li>
          <li><a href="text2.html">text2</a>
          <li><a href="text3.html">text3</a></li>
          <li><a href="text4.html">text4</a></li>          
 </ul>


<div id="content">

<font size="+3">Title</font>

<br>
<br>

Content...

<br>
<br>

</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want #navigation to display as float, you may add clear:both to your #content.

```
#content {
   background: #EBF7FF;
   width: 1024px;
   height:768px;       
   text-align: justify;
   clear:both;
}
```

But to my mind better solution would be displaying it as block and li as inline-block or display it as table and li as table-cell

Answer (score 0):

You specify a width of 100% for #navigation which is contained in a container #frame holding the content. So the #navigation takes the width of its container, thus the same width as the rest of the content inside that container because the container takes exactly the width required by the content inside.

You place that navigation *inside* the content container, so obviously it has to take room in there. If you want to avoid that simply put the navigation above the content container:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>
<body text="#000000" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" link="#FF0000" alink="#FF0000" vlink="#FF0000">

<div id="header">
    <ul id="navigation">
          <li><a href="main.html" target="_self">text1</a></li>
          <li><a href="text2.html">text2</a>
          <li><a href="text3.html">text3</a></li>
          <li><a href="text4.html">text4</a></li>          
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="frame">
  <div id="content">
  <font size="+3">Title</font>
    <br>
    Content...
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>​
```

Compare that [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/eeswu/3/).

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't really solve my problem. It's okay that the width of every element is 1024px so that's why I wrapped everything with the frame. The height of the content area is the problem because the navigation bar takes place in it (so the size of the content area is 1024px - height of navigation bar). I don't get why because the navigation is placed before the content div as you can see in my code.

Comment: @Daniel where do you expect the navigation to be placed?

Comment: @ Behnam Esmaili: It should be displayed between the header and the content area. "clear:both" helps.

Comment: I took #navigation completely out of #frame. You did not really read my answer. That way #navigation does _not_ take part of the space inside #frame. But I agree that this might not be the solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you'r navigation must occupy whole the with available and has height set to a value.set `display:table` for your navigation so it's height grows to it's content like this:

```
#navigation{
   display:table;
}
```

check [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sRWTD/2/)

Answer (score 0):

That's because `#navigation` it's floating above `#content`.

Try adding this to force `#content` to render below the navigation:

```
#content {
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do this, you don't have to bother what is coming after your navigation.

```
#navigation:after {
   clear:both;
}
```